# Is there a way to send an email from outlook to another messaging platform using a custom outlook addin?

Tags: .net, vsto, microsoft-teams, outlook-addin, office-addins

I want to build an outlook add-in using which I can share an email from outlook to another messaging platform. For example, I want to build something similar to "Share to Teams" add-in on Outlook. I'm unable to find any documentation on "share to Teams" add-in and how it's actually built. It would be helpful if you could share the documentations or resources or brief me the steps. Thank you.

I tried searching for various documentations on add-ins, but they were a little confusing. I was confused if I should use VSTO to create an add-in or Office add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Teams is a VSTO addin, but it wouldn't have any documentation regarding its internal workings. And I am not sure it would be applicable in your case anyway as you'd be sharing to some other system, not Teams.

Comment: The messaging system I am trying to integrate with outlook is within an ERP system and is a company level messaging system. Should I develop a VSTO add-in or an Office add-in (which, I just learnt, is apparently different)?

Comment: Depends - VSTO addns let you do whatever Outlook itself does, including access to the low-level MAPI properties and Windows API. JS addins pretty much only work in the context of a selected message only, but they work under all flavors of Outlook, not just desktop under Windows.